# Libgdx write and read from a server

Tags: libgdx

I want to make a math game where after you finish your game you upload some statistics about the last game, and from other app you can read it.

How can I connect to a server / ftp and upload a text file or read it?

Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What kind of statistics do you mean? Do you want to synchronize user data, like scores made, achieved levels etc, so that you can open the app on a different device and have the same data?

Or are we talking about completely different apps with different purposes?

Comment: Yea. Something like Difficulty played, equations that were answered wrong, using JSON. And i want to add the last game statistics, so on the other app you can see all the game progress by a key or username